# Reading 2 variables from a text file and looping

Tags: powershell

I have a script which I'd like to use PowerShell to `bcp` out data. I need to kick off multiple `bcp` commands and want to read 1. table name and 2. field name from a text file to populate the `bcp` command string.

Currently this doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the 2 variables.

The text file looks like:

```
table: table1
table: table2
field: field1
field: field2
```

```
# Log file time stamp:
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
# Log file name:
$LogFile = "C:\Administration\Logs\BCPEXPORTLOG_" + $LogTime + ".log"

$database = "database"
$schema = "dbo"
$table = "TableName"
$tablename = Get-Content 'C:\Administration\Scheduled Tasks\CUBTableList.txt' |
             ? { $_ -match '^\s*table:\s*' } |
             select -First 1 |
             % { ($_ -split ':\s*', 2)[1] }
$fieldname = Get-Content 'C:\Administration\Scheduled Tasks\CUBTableList.txt' |
             ? { $_ -match '^\s*field:\s*' } |
             select -First 1 |
             % { ($_ -split ':\s*', 2)[1] }

foreach ($line in Get-Content 'C:\Administration\Scheduled Tasks\CUBTableList.txt') {
    $bcp_command = "bcp 'SELECT * FROM $database.$schema.$tablename WHERE ($fieldname <=  DATEADD(ms, -3, GETDATE()))' QUERYOUT 'D:\BCPOut\$database`_$tablename.txt'  -c -U 'user' -P 'password'"
    Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile -InputObject $bcp_command -Append
    $bcp_results = Invoke-Expression $bcp_command
    Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile -InputObject $bcp_results -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed up my dodgy script.

Used import-csv instead.

```
#  Log file time stamp:
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
#  Log file name:
$LogFile = "C:\Administration\Logs\BCPEXPORTLOG_"+$LogTime+".log"

$database = "database"
$schema = "dbo"
$table = "TableName"

Import-CSV 'C:\Administration\Scheduled Tasks\CUBList.csv' | ForEach{

        $bcp_command = "bcp 'SELECT * FROM $database.$schema." + $_.tablename + " WHERE (" + $_.fieldname + " <=  DATEADD(ms, -3, GETDATE()))' QUERYOUT 'D:\BCPOut\$database`_" + $_.tablename + ".txt'  -c -U 'user' -P 'password'"
        Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile -InputObject $bcp_command -Append
        $bcp_results = Invoke-Expression $bcp_command
        Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile -InputObject $bcp_results -Append
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
$LogFile = "c:\temp\BCPEXPORTLOG_{0:MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss}.log" -f (Get-Date)
$database = "database"
$schema = "dbo"

#split with 'table:'
$Split1=(Get-Content c:\temp\CUBTableList.txt) -split 'table:'

#split fields and take only tablename <>'' and table have field
$Elements=$Split1 | %{
$Split2=$_ -split 'field:'
$table=$Split2[0];
[pscustomobject]@{TableName=$Split2[0].Trim(); Fields=$Split2[1..$($Split2.Length)] | %{$_.Trim()}} | where {$_.TableName -ne '' -and $_.Fields -ne $null}
}

$bcp_command=@()

#build bcp commands
$Elements | %{

    $TableName=$_.TableName

    $_.Fields | %{

    $bcp_command+="bcp 'SELECT * FROM {0}.{1}.{2} WHERE {3} <= DATEADD(ms, -3, GETDATE())' QUERYOUT 'D:\BCPOut\{0}_{2}_{3}.txt'  -c -U 'user' -P 'password'" -f $database, $schema, $TableName, $_

    }
}

#run commands
$bcp_command | %{

   $_ | out-file $LogFile -Append

   try
   {
       $result=Invoke-Expression $_
   }
   catch
   {
       $result=$_.Exception.Message
   }
   finally
   {
       $result | Out-File $LogFile -Append
   }


}
```